# how do to use @media with viewport?

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to change object style based on window size. So

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

will work for all objects.. But my child div size is based on parent div size. I want to change style of child object based on window size but not parent object size.. Here is a simple HTML.. Is it possible? to calculate style based on viewport

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <style>
            .parent {
                background: red;
            }
            .myDiv {
                background: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class='parent'>
            parent div
            <div class='myDiv'>
                child div
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By window size, what do you mean `height`, `width` or both.

Comment: You will need JS for this.

Comment: window size I mean window size but not size of parent object

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can write

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      body {
        background: blue;
      }
    .myDiv{
        background: white;
    }

}
```

It will affecct only tags with class .myDiv